# Import SQL server database without empty columns

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery

I'm importing a set of tables from a SQL Server DB to Power BI Desktop.

It's a huge database and I'm selecting only some of its tables.

However, these tables have empty columns or columns with zeros only, so I've created two M functions to apply to each and every table to "clean" them.

Is it possible to specify an SQL command in the import settings to fetch only "valid" columns, thus avoiding loading them to Power BI and use custom functions?

Can anyone please share sucha a SQL command?

Thank you!

Comment: filter them out with a where clause?

Comment: As you're saying  in the "import settings" I ***assume*** the data is coming from an external source, maybe Excel? Sounds like you need to add a filter in your ETL process; it's not Data Engine's fault if a bunch of rows with the value `NULL` where inserted into a table. Fix the ETL process, and then the rows won't be there any more.

Comment: Select [column name 1], [column name 2] from [table name] where {condition} will only load relevant columns and rows.

Comment: @Larnu.  "I'm importing a set of tables from a SQL Server DB to Power BI Desktop"

Comment: @Larnu not a "bunch of rows", but of columns

Comment: Why don't you perform basic ETL to fit your needs ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an initial SQL query in the connection object. If you click on the settings for it and open the advanced section, you can enter it there (screenshot is from the MySQL connector but I'm sure the SQL Server one is similar).

[image]

The output code would look something like

```
SQL.Database("sql.server.address:1234", "your_sql_server", [Query="SELECT columns, you, want FROM table_you_want"])
```

However note that if you are using the native connector in Power Query/BI, it attempts to convert whatever you do in Power Query into SQL on the back-end. If you right click on steps in your PQ process and click "Native Query" it will show you the SQL code it is converting to. If at some point that is greyed out it means whatever you were doing was something it couldn't convert.

Comment: Hello @Wedge, thanks for your support! My goal is to improve the performance of this large database. I notice the file size is reduced whenever certain columns are eliminated in Power Query M, so it seems the columns deleted in Power Query Editor aren't loaded (or queried) in SQL database, is this right?